# Crash on accessing a key that should be in an NSDictionary created from JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, crash, nsdictionary

I have a `dictionary` that sometimes reads a null value from some JSON data. When I do :

```
 NSDictionary *caption=[image objectForKey:@"caption"]; //crash here!
```

Where the field `caption` is there but null, (in the JSON, `caption:null`), I get a crash.
How can I eliminate this?

I can check for null later on with:

```
 NSDictionary *caption=[image objectForKey:@"caption"];
 NSString *text=@"";
 if( caption!=NULL  )
 {text=[caption objectForKey:@"text"];  }
```

but the crash comes even before this.

This is how my dictionary is being built:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
 NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
 NSArray *myResults=[result objectForKey:@"data"];
 long count=[myResults count];

 for(NSDictionary *image in myResults)
 {
       NSDictionary *links=[image objectForKey:@"images"];
       NSDictionary *standard=[links objectForKey:@"standard"];
       NSString *url=[standard objectForKey:@"url"];

       NSLog(@"image:%@",image);
       NSDictionary *caption=[image objectForKey:@"caption"]; //CRASH
```

Comment: You can't have an actual null/nil in an NSDictionary, unless the dictionary has been corrupted somehow.  Are you sure the crash is coming from that specific statement?  What is the exception that occurs?

Comment: Post the code that really causes the crash. Also include the full error message.

Comment: Note that you *can* have an NSNull object in an NSDictionary, and that will NSLog as something like "(NULL)" (I forget the exact message).  An NSNull object will not be == null/nil, and will result in an "Invalid selector" exception if blindly used in the next statement.  An NSNull object *will* compare `== [NSNull null]`, however, so you can use that to check for it.

Comment: Yes i am sure. the dictionary is made from a json file, and the json has a null object under this field ..

Comment: @HotLicks yes you can. when you create a dictionary from a json , and than dig in and get the sub dictionary(like me) you can get a null object

Comment: I repeat, you **cannot** create an NSDictionary with a `nil` value in it.  Show us a dump of your dictionary.  (And show us the JSON that created it.)

Comment: see my edit please.(your down votes are not affect me as you)

Comment: @Curnelious You can create a dictionary with an instance of an `NSNull` object but Hot Licks is correct - you CAN'T create a dictionary with a `nil` value or key.

Comment: FYI - the down votes are for not providing sufficient details in your question to help answer it. Until you point out the actual line of code causing the crash and the error message of the crash, your question really can't be answered - hence the down votes. Your latest update still doesn't provide this information.

Comment: @maddy , can or can't, question was how do i check for a nil/NULL/whatever

Comment: @Curnelious Saying "whatever" doesn't help. You are writing software for a computer. Precision is critical. You must be explicitly clear in what you mean because it can make a HUGE difference.

Comment: I told you how to check for NSNull.  In the 3rd comment..

Comment: So what does the NSLog of `image` look like??  Show us that, and show us the original JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that NSDictionary *caption=[image objectForKey:@"caption"]; would return a dictionary?

Anyway, the way to check to see if it's JSON null is:

```
if ([image[@"caption"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) { // it's null }
```

Note that dictionaries and arrays can't contain nil. nil isn't an object value. [NSNull null] is a special object that is the equivalent of nil and can be used in places where nil can't.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: No need to use `isEqual` -- since NSNull is a singleton class you can simply use `==`.